# Show create and upload button only inside specific folder in alfresco Doclib

Tags: alfresco-share

I am creating one project through create project action in alfresco doclib, which i shown in below attached screen shot. i have to create that project only inside document library folder. because i have set one rule on document library to create some dynamic default project structure through java script code. its working fine.

but now i am facing one big challenge, that is inside every sub folder i am getting that create project and upload option also. but i dont want to allow user to create the project inside every sub folder. i just want to show that create and upload doclib action only inside document library. and internal directory i am creating through java script code. So can anyone please help me how can i do this.

Thanks in advance.

And please refer below attached screenshot for detail understanding of my requirment.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom-share-config-custom.xml, you can use an evaluator to check your conditions for a **DocLibActions**.

This is an example for an action which will only be shown for node of the **x:myType** type :

**share-amp-slingshot-application-context.xml** :

```
<bean id="evaluator.doclib.action.myCondition" class="org.alfresco.web.evaluator.NodeTypeEvaluator" >
   <property name="types">
        <list>
            <value>x:myType</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**share-config-custom.xml** :

```
<action id="example-action" type="javascript" label="....">
    <evaluator>evaluator.doclib.action.myCondition</evaluator>
 </action>
<evaluator>evaluator.doclib.action.myCondition</evaluator
```

But this **doesn't work** for top menu like create-content.
What you can do is creating an specific rôle for your need like [this](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Permissions_in_Share) :

```
<permissionGroup name="SomeUserPermissions" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
      <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Collaborator" type="cm:cmobject" />
</permissionGroup>
```

and then apply this specific permission to users on this folder, and then modify your code like this

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary" > 
     <create-content> 
         <content id="newFolderId" mimetype="text/plain" icon="folder" label="Create Project" itemid="bd:project">
                      <param name="page">create-content?destination={nodeRef}&amp;itemId=cm:content&amp;mimeType=text/plain</param>
        <permissions>
           <permission allow="true">SomeUserPermissions</permission>
        </permissions>
         <content> 
     </create-content> 
</config>
```

Finally, I would suggest you to look as the document called **share-documentlibrary-config.xml** in your share war which will help you to understand how it works.

There is, for example, this piece of documentation about the  tag :

> Create Content menu items, can be of 3 types matching the usual doclib action config:
>
> - "link" - accepts a "href" param that will be passed a nodeRef token for substitution, used for external links
> - "pagelink" - accepts a "page" param that will be passed a nodeRef token for substitution, used for Share links
> - "javascript" - accepts & "function" param of an action that will get the current folder item as first argument.
>
>   ```
>    I.e.
>    <content id="plain-text" label="create-content.text" icon="text" type="pagelink">
>       <param name="page">create-content?destination={nodeRef}&amp;itemId=cm:content&amp;mimeType=text/plain</param>
>       <permissions>
>          <permission allow="true">SomeUserPermissions</permission>
>       </permissions>
>    </content>
>   ```
>
> Note that the "CreateChildren" permission is always required and will disable the entire menu if no granted for a folder.
>
> Also note that the old/untyped simple config still is allowed, the config snippet below will automatically be converted to a "pagelink" as in the example above.
>
> ```
>      <content id="plain-text" label="create-content.text" icon="text" itemid="cm:content" mimetype="text/plain" 
>      permission="SomeUserPermissions"/>
> ```

Comment: Hi Akash, Actually i am not getting where exactly should i apply that evaluator which you have provided. its not working me in my case. Can you please tell me exactly where should i use that evaluator in my code.  
  <config evaluator="string-compare"  condition="DocumentLibrary" >
    <create-content>
        <content id="newFOlderId" mimetype="text/plain" icon="folder" label="Create Project" itemid="bd:project"/>      
       
         
    </create-content>
   </config>    This is the code i am using to display create projectaction. and i want to hide create, upload buttons as per attached

Comment: As far as I see, you can't use an evaluator for this specific case. I've been giving you an example for an action (right-menu actions). BUT you can use specific permission. I update my answer to explain it to you.

Comment: Hii Akah, Have you tried this code,  Actually i tried a lot. But its not working?? Can you please help?  :(